# opsworks-init: Agent installation failed, errors in dependency resolution

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, dependency-management, aws-opsworks

I am trying to manually register an instance to an OpsWorks layer using the command below:

`aws opsworks register --use-instance-profile --infrastructure-class ec2 --region us-east-1 --stack-id {STACK_ID} --local`

But when I try to execute the command, it returns the error below:

```
Error: Package: cvs-1.11.23-16.9.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-main)
       Requires: perl(getopts.pl)
       Available: 4:perl-5.16.3-286.38.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-main)
           perl(getopts.pl)
       Installed: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.43.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
           Not found
Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.17-196.172.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-main)
       Requires: glibc(x86-64) = 2.17-196.172.amzn1
       Installed: glibc-2.17-324.189.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
           glibc(x86-64) = 2.17-324.189.amzn1
       Available: glibc-2.17-196.172.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-main)
           glibc(x86-64) = 2.17-196.172.amzn1
Error: Package: glibc-headers-2.17-196.172.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-main)
       Requires: glibc(x86-64) = 2.17-196.172.amzn1
       Installed: glibc-2.17-324.189.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
           glibc(x86-64) = 2.17-324.189.amzn1
       Available: glibc-2.17-196.172.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-main)
           glibc(x86-64) = 2.17-196.172.amzn1
Error: Package: rpm-build-4.11.3-21.75.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-main)
       Requires: rpm = 4.11.3-21.75.amzn1
       Installed: rpm-4.11.3-40.80.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
           rpm = 4.11.3-40.80.amzn1
       Available: rpm-4.11.3-21.75.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-main)
           rpm = 4.11.3-21.75.amzn1
...
[Wed, 19 Apr 2023 12:02:41 +0000] opsworks-init: Agent installation failed.
[Wed, 19 Apr 2023 12:02:41 +0000] opsworks-init: Please verify the log files found under /var/log/aws/opsworks and submit findings to AWS Support.
```

I have tried to manually install each of the missing dependency via `yum install` but the same error occurred. I have also tried the `rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest`